# "STOP! Look and Listen" really?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing a close vote https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4950232

And, It flashed that message, saying my "audit" failed

The question was:

> So, Xamarin just announced Xamarin.Forms - http://xamarin.com/forms
>
> What are the thought on supporting this, it looks pretty sweet for
>   "simple" UI's.
>
> Guess this goes out to Stuart.

How on earth does it belong to SO?

It has got 5 upvotes.

So, does it mean that any question which has got a bunch of upvotes ok to SO?

Comment: Bad audits do happen...

Comment: Ye gods. Downvoted and voted to close.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, followed the suit

Comment: More [MvvmCross goodness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224376/mvvmcross-experiences-hindsight-limitations).

Comment: "Listen"?? is there audio I am missing?

Comment: Probably another chat room thing.

Comment: You've just signed, sealed, delivered that podcast, ups, I mean, Audit.

Comment: “STOP! Look and Listen”. Just plain rude in my opinion.

Comment: "Stop! Look and Listen" is from the old green cross road edumacation PIFs with the Green Cross Code Man (David Prowse, what played Darth Vader)