# Should I, “STOP! Look and Listen” to this audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing a question from the *triage* queue earlier today I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16771960) audit. Once I reported it as off topic I was asked to *STOP! Look and Listen*, because apparently I failed!

The OP is asking to apply some changes on their editor. To my understanding this type of questions are off topic, although, it has received a high number of upvotes.

Here is the question:
[How to remove right side file preview in vs code editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774709/how-to-remove-right-side-file-preview-in-vs-code-editor)

Am I wrong or this could be [another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256855/stop-look-and-listen-really) failed audit?

Comment: Why is it off-topic? Questions about tools used by programmers are on topic here, according to the Help Center. Don't you think Visual Studio Code  would qualify?

Comment: @CodyGray Before [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44774709/revisions), the question didn't look good. I would have voted to close it as well.

Comment: Let the meta effect begin :)

Comment: My edit was pretty trivial. The most significant change was tweaking the wording to remove the potentially objectionable word "hell", and rearranging it so the image came before the question. I don't think the edit did anything to "salvage" the question. If it was off-topic before, it would still be off-topic now.

Comment: Why does a perfectly good and clear and on-topic question get downvoted (presumably due to the meta effect [since all of the downvotes were from today](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44774709/timeline)) just because someone thought it was a bad audit

Comment: @psubsee2003 Perhaps "lack of research"? The topicality of questions about IDEs has been discussed many, many times on Meta, and is listed as on-topic in the help center.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Maybe, and it certainly isn't my place to tell others how to vote, but seeing as it survived 3 weeks without getting a downvote (while picking up 14 upvotes, 1000 views, and being used as an audit 7 times), and then getting 4 downvotes after this question was asked suggests downvoters were reacting to the suggestion that it was a bad audit.  May be an unfair assumption to make on my part though.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sorry, I thought you were talking about this meta post, but now that I clicked on your link, and read your response, you were actually talking about the question on main. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about your IDE are on topic on SO.

So no, there's nothing wrong with that audit at all.